# writing function to adjust igraph networks in list objects

Tags: r, igraph

I have a list() of networks from the igraph package and I would like to adjust them in mass. This is what I would to do, in the format of a single network graph object.

```
  
# $Weight to E(nw)$weight
  E(nw)$weight <- E(nw)$Weight

# edge weight to width 
  E(nw)$width <- 1+(log(E(nw)$weight)*6)
  
#arrow size
  E(nw)$arrow.size <- .7
  
#figures
c.colours <- c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow")[membership(nw.community)]

png(file = "... nw.png",
    width = 1800,
    height = 1200,
    units = "px")

plot(nw.community, nw,
     col = c.colours,
     mark.col = adjustcolor(c.colours, alpha.f = 0.4),
     mark.border = adjustcolor(c.colours, alpha.f = 1),
     edge.curved = .15)

dev.off()
```

How would I would I write a function to do that for a list object? I don't know much about writing functions or loops.

Comment: It's unclear to me what values you are looping over here. What would change in each loop? There are basic guides to looping in R out there you can find: https://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-inflammation/15-supp-loops-in-depth/.

Comment: maybe this could be useful. You just need to write a function that does everything you want, and then apply that function to all elements of the list https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62695323/how-can-i-calculate-network-measures-separately-for-different-periods-using-igra/62696089#62696089